# Would the detaching of dendrites from electrodes in a cell, result in the crystal dissolving back into the electrolyte?

Tags: electrochemistry, crystal-structure

Dendrites that form on the electrodes of cells shorten the cell's lifetime, and result in reduced capacity before the end of life.

If the dendrites could be detached from the electrode, would they then dissolve back into the electrolyte, or would they remain as solids suspended in it? How does this effect battery lifetime and capacity?